# JS: group array of objects by date range keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input:

```
const calendarData = [
  {
    customerName: "Mark",
    startDatetime: "2022-08-10T17:10:11.000+0000",
    endDatetime: "2022-08-12T17:10:55.000+0000",
    description: 'Mark Description'
  },
    {
    customerName: "Tristan",
    startDatetime: null,
    endDatetime: "2022-08-10T10:10:55.000+0000",
    description: 'Tristan Description'
  },
  {
    customerName: "Andrew",
    startDatetime: "2022-08-14T17:10:11.000+0000",
    endDatetime: null,
    description: 'Andrew Description'
  },
  {
    customerName: "Kevin",
    startDatetime: "2022-08-10T17:10:11.000+0000",
    endDatetime: "2022-08-11T17:10:55.000+0000",
    description: 'Kevin Description'
  }
];
```

The goal is to map calendar data to agenda format. A few points to take into consideration:

1. If startDatetime and endDatetime is more than 1 day, spread dates into a range;
2. If startDatetime is null, use only endDatetime to get a date and vice versa.

Expected output:

```
const expected = {
  '2022-08-10': [
    {
      customerName: 'Mark'
      description: 'Mark Description'
    },
    {
      customerName: 'Tristan',
      description: 'Tristan Description'
    },
    {
      customerName: "Kevin",
      description: 'Kevin Description'
    }
  ],
  '2022-08-11': [
    {
      customerName: 'Mark'
      description: 'Mark Description'
    },
    {
      customerName: "Kevin",
      description: 'Kevin Description'
    }
  ],
  '2022-08-12': [
    {
      customerName: 'Mark'
      description: 'Mark Description'
    },
  ],
  '2022-08-14': [
    {
      customerName: 'Andrew',
      description: 'Andrew Description'
    },
  ]
}
```

I was trying using reduce and Object property, but how can I spread dates and group it?

```
const result = () => {
   return calendarData.reduce((c, item) => {
     
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the JavaScript, see [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: I am not sure why is this closed, the question & the duplicate mapped to custom date range sorting have no connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment` library to reduce it to your desired format.

```
const DATE_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD";

const result = calendarData.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (
    curr.startDatetime &&
    curr.endDatetime &&
    moment(curr.startDatetime).format(DATE_FORMAT) !==
      moment(curr.endDatetime).format(DATE_FORMAT)
  ) {
    let date = moment(curr.startDatetime);
    while (moment(date).isBefore(moment(curr.endDatetime))) {
      console.log(date.format(DATE_FORMAT), curr.customerName);
      if (prev[date.format(DATE_FORMAT)])
        prev[date.format(DATE_FORMAT)].push({
          customerName: curr.customerName,
          description: curr.description
        });
      else
        prev[date.format(DATE_FORMAT)] = [
          {
            customerName: curr.customerName,
            description: curr.description
          }
        ];
      date = date.add(1, "day");
    }
  } else {
    if (curr.startDatetime) {
      const startDate = moment(curr.startDatetime).format(DATE_FORMAT);
      if (prev[startDate])
        prev[startDate].push({
          customerName: curr.customerName,
          description: curr.description
        });
      else
        prev[startDate] = [
          {
            customerName: curr.customerName,
            description: curr.description
          }
        ];
    }
    if (curr.endDatetime) {
      const endDate = moment(curr.endDatetime).format(DATE_FORMAT);
      if (prev[endDate])
        prev[endDate].push({
          customerName: curr.customerName,
          description: curr.description
        });
      else
        prev[endDate] = [
          {
            customerName: curr.customerName,
            description: curr.description
          }
        ];
    }
  }

  return prev;
}, {});
```

There is a lot of repeated code,  but it gets the job done.

First, we check if both the start and end dates are not null and are not the same day. If that condition is `true`, then we loop from the start date to the end date with the step as a day. If the date is present in the result object, append it to the corresponding array. If not, make a new array with the required object.

If we don't have both dates, then we add the object to the array of whichever object is present.